# Drupal CiviCRM update account info with CiviCRM profile

Tags: drupal, profile, user-account

I want to allow my registered Drupal users the ability to update certain information in their CiviCRM contact record. I've created a profile and made enabled the following

- Standalone form or directory
- Drupal user registration View/Edit
- Drupal user account

The profile now shows up on the user's Drupal account page and is prepopulated with any information that is already in their contact record, which is great. I did notice, however, that if I use the link found by 'Use Profile-Create mode' the information is not prepopulated for that same user. Is this to be expected or might I have done something wrong?

I would also like to be able to use the Current Employer field as a select list whereas I can have a group of employers show up. We have employers such as The Nature Conservancy and people put in TNC, Nature Conservancy, etc. and that creates many iterations of the same organization. I was able to use this via Drupal's webform CiviCRM integration module but it does not seem possible with just the CiviCRM profiles. Is this also true?

What I currently have is the CiviCRM profile on the user's account page and then I need to redirect them to the webform to collect their employer information which is not ideal. If I get rid of the CiviCRM profile and put everything in the webform then it no longer is attached to their user account page in Drupal.

Just wondering if others have dealt with this same thing and how they went around solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Create Mode" means just that, creating a new contact, thus the fields will appear blank. You want edit mode, with a url like `/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=N` where N is the ID of the profile.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I used /civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=N where N was the ID of the profile and it worked perfectly.